# Apache reverse proxy fails without trailing slash

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I'm currently trying to set up a Reverse Proxy with Apache. I went with the following config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my-server

  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLProxyVerify none 
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass "/c/"  "https://other.server.com/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/c/"  "https://other.server.com/"

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I've encountered is that when I navigate to `localhost:8080/c/slug/` it works as expected, yet when I navigate to `localhost:8080/c/slug` it redirects me to `localhost:8080/slug` instead of getting the content from the proxied server.

When inspecting the call headers I found a `301: Moved permanently`.

[image: HTTP headers]

On the other hand, while inspecting the call that works, it all appears fine:

[image]

I've tried the following ideas, but none have happened to work:

### RewriteRule

Adding a rewrite rule:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule "slug$" "slug/" [L,R=301]
```

### Explicitly typing the URL

Explicitly typing the URL I'm trying to access without the forward slash:

```
  ProxyPass "/c/slug"  "https://other.server.com/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/c/slug"  "https://other.server.com/"
```

I have also tried turning on and off the `ProxyRequests`, but also didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ProxyPassReverse should be taking care of correctly rewriting HTTP redirect headers but will only rewrite a few specific ones (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) so start by inspecting the headers you get when you access the URI without a trailing / - also including or omitting the trailing / in the ProxyPass directive should be the same on both the local path prefix and the remote URI

Comment: @HBruijn I inspected the headers, although I don't really understand the results. I added them to the question. Does the 301 tell you anything that might be going on?

Comment: This is most probably a configuration issue on other.server.com, not your reverse proxy. Fetch `https://other.server.com/slug` and see what happens.

Comment: The *"moved permanently - **from disk cache**"*  shows at least one of your problems. A **Permanent redirect** (the result of your testing with `[L,R=301]` flags?) is exactly that: permanent and  will be cached by a web browser. If you made a mistake and don't clear your caches (or don't do each new test in a new anonymous window)  then any changes you make in the server configuration won't become apparent  as your webbrowser will change the request for you even before it gets sent to a server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider @HBruijn so I just went and checked the `other.server.com` and there is something fishy going on. It does deliver the content on both urls, both with and without the forward slash, but when I GET the content without the forward slash it does return a 301. Do you think this might have to do with my proxy returning that 301 and not displaying content? I have tested this on an anonymous window.

Comment: The problem is that the target server returns a 301 redirect to "/slug/", which does not match your proxy definition anymore. A proper rewrite rule on your server that is handled before the proxy should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but in my case I was redirecting a VirtualHost from HTTP to a VirtualHost with HTTPS, and in my Redirect directive it was missing the final **/**.

For example: Redirect / https://localhost

And I solved with: Redirect / https://localhost**/**